# Symfony ExceptionListener: how to handle dependencies?

Tags: php, exception, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm experimenting with my own framework based on symfony2 components, like described in a tutorial series by Fabien Potencier. Everything is clear to me so far except for one thing.

I've established a container builder described in the last part of the tutorial:
http://fabien.potencier.org/article/62/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-12

I've added twig to the containerbuilder:

```
$sc->register('twigLoader', 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem')
   ->setArguments(array('%templatePath%'));
$sc->register('twig', 'Twig_Environment')
   ->setArguments(array(new Reference('twigLoader'), array()));
```

Than there is the part with the ErrorController which will be called when an exception occurs:

```
$sc->register('listener.exception', 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener')
   ->setArguments(array('Calendar\\Controller\\ErrorController::exceptionAction'));
```

But to display a proper error page which is rendered by twig I need the twig dependency in the error controller. How can I do this?

Please note that I don't use the full symfony framework, just the components!

Comment: Been awhile since I went through that tutorial.  Excellent set of articles.  The exception listener basically generates a new sub request and ends up calling ErrorController::exceptionAction.  The exceptionAction is where you render your exception error page.  So that is the class to which you need to inject twig into.  To do that you will need to register your ErrorController as a service and then inject that into the listener instead of a hard coded class path.  I don;t have the exact code to copy/paste for you but at least it points you in the correct direction.

Comment: I already thought in that way but the ExceptionListener expects a string with the controller name and method through the "setArguments()" call. I couldn't find a way to call the ErrorController as a service. Any further advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

D'Oh... I already had it. The only thing I had to change is that the error controller doesn't have to return a response object. Instead it's returning an array now and than my normal response listener with the twig object is reacting and I have a custom error page processed by twig...

Comment: So you put in your own custom response listener as opposed to adding twig to the controller?

Comment: Yep. The tutorial only used normal php scripts as "templates" so I added:

    $sc->register('listener.twig_response', 'Simplex\TwigResponseListener')
       ->setArguments(array(new Reference('twig')))
    ;

And I changed the controllers, that they only return an array which holds the variables for the twig templates. Only the ErrorController still had a "return new Response(...)". Returning an array like all other controllers helped.

Comment: It's great you got it working but you really want to be able to use the default ExceptionListener.  Customizing the controller is the usual approach.  You said the ExceptionListener was excepting a string.  What it really does is accept any controller executable.  What you want to do is to pass it an array with the controller object as the first element and the method name as the second element.  Something like: array(new Reference('my_exception_controller'),'exceptionAction').  Understanding this process is important.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Now, after your last reply, I found out why. I wrote "setArguments(array(new Reference('errorcontroller'), 'exceptionAction'))" but it has to be "setArguments(array(array(new Reference('errorcontroller'), 'exceptionAction')))" (one array element more). Now the error controller puts out twig content independet to the response listener.

Thanks a lot for your help. Now I've two working variants how to do it. ;)